# How can i refer to all of my <a> tags in CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to make it so that all of my  tags look plain when they show up on the screen also after I visit them or if I hover over them.  I put all of my divs in a wrapper and tried to refer to them but it didn't seem to work.  I don't really need the wrapper if I could just refer to everything using a:hover ... that would be fine.

here is my HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="settings_button">
<span class="settings_text">
Settings
</span>
</div>
<div id="posts_button">
<span class="one_bar_text">
Posts
</span>
</div>

<a href="#" alt="posts">
<div id="posts_button_dark">
<span class="one_bar_text">
Posts
</span>
</div>
</a>
<div id="profile_button">
<span class="one_bar_text">
Profile
</span>
</div>
<div id="profile_button_dark">
<span class="one_bar_text">
Profile
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is my CSS

```
#wrapper a:link {
    color: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
#wrapper a:visited {
    color: none;
}
#wrapper a:hover {
    color: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

I will be making most of my divs into links i just haven't yet. and i would like to avoid having to reference each div's  tag on my CSS page

so i changed my CSS to this

```
a:link {
    color: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

but the link is still being underlined on hover over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either links or buttons, not `<divs>`.

If you do decide to go with the current markup:

```
div[id*=button] {
    ...
}
```

---

If you decide to sober up (seriously, don't use divs!)

Just `a` or `button` will do.

```
a {
    color: red;
}
```

Will color all links in red.

Note that it will catch **all** links, as in in the content area, the nav, the footer. Everywhere.

Comment: If you need to match specificity with other rules with pseudo-classes, and you don't have any `<a>` anchors without `href`, use `a:link, a:visited` instead.

Comment: so a:hover { color: none; text-transform: none;} should stop it from being underlined? when i hover over it

Comment: @noWayhome: Correct. Note that it won't work in your current markup, as you are using divs. Switch to buttons or links, as they are more suitable for that kind of job.

Comment: @truth im using the div to bring in background images

Comment: so i should just go with links and keep the same id's?

Comment: Links can have background images as well. I say go with links with classes (not necessarily IDs).

Answer (score 3):

```
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is highly questionable, but it addresses the question you asked. You don’t need any fancy selectors, since any setting in a page style sheet that applies to an element will override browser defaults.

You just need to set an explicitly color (or use `inherit`, but IE does not support it), and to kill underlining, you need to set `text-decoration`, not `text-transform`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Just use **a**

> a:link {
>       color: none;
>       text-transform: none;
>   }
>
> a:visited {
>       color: none; }
>
> a:hover {
>       color: none;
>       text-transform: none; }